# How to update a field on a new INSERT and do this in a TRIGGER?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

So I am using oracle to run my sql scripts. `:NEW` is a built-in object provided by Oracle, representing the new record to be inserted into the table which the trigger is associated to.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "TUTORIAL4C"
BEFORE INSERT ON "MOVIES" FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CASE
  WHEN :NEW.RATING = 'G'
    UPDATE MOVIES SET :NEW.COST = :NEW.COST - 0.10;
    UPDATE MOVIES SET :NEW.DESCRIPTION = :NEW.DESCRIPTION + 'Recommended for all audiences';
  WHEN :NEW.RATING = 'PG'
    UPDATE MOVIES SET :NEW.COST = :NEW.COST + 0.20;
    UPDATE MOVIES SET :NEW.DESCRIPTION = :NEW.DESCRIPTION + 'Parental guidance for young viewers';
  WHEN :NEW.RATING = 'PG-13'
    UPDATE MOVIES SET :NEW.COST = :NEW.COST + 0.20;
    UPDATE MOVIES SET :NEW.DESCRIPTION = :NEW.DESCRIPTION + 'Parental guidance for young viewers';
  WHEN :NEW.RATING = 'R'
    UPDATE MOVIES SET :NEW.COST = :NEW.COST + 0.60;
    UPDATE MOVIES SET :NEW.DESCRIPTION = :NEW.DESCRIPTION + 'Recommended for mature audiences';
  WHEN :NEW.RATING = 'NC-17'
    UPDATE MOVIES SET :NEW.COST = :NEW.COST + 1;
    UPDATE MOVIES SET :NEW.DESCRIPTION = :NEW.DESCRIPTION + 'Mature audiences only';
END;
/
```

That is what I have attempted. So when a new insert is attempted this TRIGGER is supposed to update the new record's `COST` and `DESCRIPTION` field differently according to its `RATING` field value.

There are things that I am not sure of am I able to use `:NEW` like a table name? And should I use `:NEW` instead of `MOVIES` in the `UPDATE` statements?

Also please point out other things on why this won't work as intended and tell me how to fix it. It is just a tutorial problem by the way, purely for educational purposes and not assessment.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the create table script for the movies table? Off the top of my head, you just need to do something like: `:new.cost = :new.cost - 0.1;` - it's a variable you're trying to update, not a row in a table (since it's a BEFORE trigger, the data you're trying to insert hasn't got as far as making it into the table!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using triggers I highly recommend you to thoroughly study these papers:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG50000

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS020

---

Your trigger cannot work due to **Mutating table restriction**
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS759

> The mutating-table restriction prevents the trigger from querying or modifying the table that the triggering statement is modifying. When a row-level trigger encounters a mutating table, ORA-04091 occurs, the effects of the trigger and triggering statement are rolled back, and control returns to the user or application that issued the triggering statement...

In simple words -in "for each row" trigger  you cannot use any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements that reference the same table for which this trigger is fired, because you will got ORA-04091 error. 
In your example all `UPDATE MOVIES SET ...` within a trigger will not work.

---

To modify data inserted into table you need to use NEW pseudorecord and an assignment operator := (see these links for details on pseudorecords):
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG99934
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955

Just:

```
 :NEW.COST := :NEW.COST + 0.20;
 :NEW.DESCRIPTION := :NEW.DESCRIPTION || 'Parental guidance for young viewers';
```

---

Another error in your example is bad syntax of CASE statement.
The proper syntax is:

```
CASE
WHEN condition_1 THEN statements_1
WHEN condition_2 THEN statements_2
...
WHEN condition_n THEN statements_n
[ ELSE
  else_statements ]
END CASE;
```

see this link for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS99972

There is no `END CASE` and `THEN` keywords in your example, thus it cannot even compile.

---

Yet another error in this example is that you are using `+` operator on string values, for example:

```
:NEW.DESCRIPTION = :NEW.DESCRIPTION + 'Parental guidance for young viewers';
```

You will get for sure:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

You need to use || concatenation operator for strings, in this way:

```
 :NEW.DESCRIPTION = :NEW.DESCRIPTION || 'Parental guidance for young viewers';
```

---

Below is an example of trigger that should compile, and should work:

```
create or replace trigger "TUTORIAL4C"
    BEFORE INSERT ON "MOVIES"
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN :NEW.RATING = 'G' THEN
            :NEW.COST := :NEW.COST - 0.10;
            :NEW.DESCRIPTION := :NEW.DESCRIPTION || 'Recommended for all audiences';
        WHEN :NEW.RATING = 'PG' THEN
            :NEW.COST := :NEW.COST + 0.20;
           :NEW.DESCRIPTION := :NEW.DESCRIPTION || 'Parental guidance for young viewers';
        WHEN :NEW.RATING = 'PG-13' THEN
           :NEW.COST := :NEW.COST + 0.20;
           :NEW.DESCRIPTION := :NEW.DESCRIPTION || 'Parental guidance for young viewers';
        WHEN :NEW.RATING = 'R' THEN
            :NEW.COST := :NEW.COST + 0.60;
            :NEW.DESCRIPTION := :NEW.DESCRIPTION || 'Recommended for mature audiences';
        WHEN :NEW.RATING = 'NC-17' THEN
            :NEW.COST := :NEW.COST + 1;
           :NEW.DESCRIPTION := :NEW.DESCRIPTION || 'Mature audiences only';
     END CASE;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

In oracle Trigger , you can know the old value and the new value of a specifique column of a specifique table . example :

lets say you `insert into MOVIES (Description,Rating) values('Harry Potter',8.0);`

in this DML the trigger well execute because you have assigned `before insert`

in this scenario `Description` and  `Rating` has only `:new.Description` and   `:new.Rating` because you have insert them now and value did not change .
when you insert new values to a column , the old value will be null.

now if you assigned in your trigger `before update` and you

`update movies set Description='harry potter 2' where Rating=8.0;`

now if you select `:old.description` it will return the old value `'Harry Potter'`

as for your example fix this please  from

`= :NEW.DESCRIPTION + 'Recommended for mature audiences';`

to

`= :NEW.DESCRIPTION||'Recommended for mature audiences';`

and check this would it work ?

```
WHEN :NEW.RATING = 'G'
            UPDATE MOVIES SET COST = :NEW.COST - 0.10;
            UPDATE MOVIES SET DESCRIPTION = :NEW.DESCRIPTION||'Recommended for all audiences';
```